# How to customize partner t-field-options in qweb reports

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 and I want to add two customized fields **RC** and **Code_TVA** in a report for the partner information .  I have added Rc and Code_TVA in **t-field-options** but there is no difference. Any Help please ??

partner_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <openerp>
 <data>
  <record id="res_partner_view_purchase_buttons_TVA_RC" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">num.TVA.RC.res.partner.view.purchase.</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='website']" position="after">
                    <field name="Code_TVA" select="1" placeholder="Code TVA"/>
                    <field name="RC" select="1" placeholder="Num RC"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
  </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Partner.py

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 from openerp import fields,models,api
 from openerp import tools

 import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
 from openerp.tools.translate import _


 class partner(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'res.partner'
 Code_TVA = fields.Char(string="Code de TVA")
 RC = fields.Char(string="Num Registre de Commerce")
```

purchase_report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
   <template id="report_purchasequotation_document" inherit_id="purchase.report_purchasequotation_document">
     <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1']" position="replace">
     <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div t-field="o.partner_id" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;, &quot;phone&quot;, &quot;fax&quot;, &quot;Code_TVA&quot;, &quot;RC&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: true, &quot;phone_icons&quot;: true}"/>
                <p t-if="o.partner_id.vat">VAT: <span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/></p>

        </div>

     </xpath>

</template>
```

Comment: This is a help site.  Either show what you are trying to do with code and ask specifically or try another site where you can hire people to do your job.

Comment: I'm asking for help that's why i post this question

Comment: my comment was meant to tell you that we wont do your work for you.  You have to do the heavy lifting and people will assist you if they can checking your code or errors.  Check the rules, my words my seem harsh but they are not directed to dissuade you from posting, just read the rules and you will be ok.

Comment: I didn't  askyou to do the work for me! It seems you didn't  understand my message ! I just wanted guidance or help  to solve a problem I came across ! I thought you might help . If you are not wiling to, that's a horse of another colour!

Comment: Please check how this site works.  I was just moderating your question.  Read the guidelines, I was guiding you on the usage of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer

```
<div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
<div t-field="o.partner_id"
    t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone", "fax"], "no_marker": true, "phone_icons": true}'/>
    <p t-if="o.partner_id.Code_TVA">Code_TVA: <span t-field="o.partner_id.Code_TVA"/></p>
    <p t-if="o.partner_id.RC">RC: <span t-field="o.partner_id.RC"/></p>
    <p t-if="o.partner_id.vat">VAT: <span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/></p>

</div>
```